# Auto submit form when user try to reload page or click on go back button

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on online exam portal when the user gives the exam I want to when the user tries to page reload or go back page, auto-submit the form with giving a warning message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = function() {
    $('#form_id').submit();
   return true;

     // if I use alert here alert work but form not submitting

  };

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**onbeforeunload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and `event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type`

```
<body onbeforeunload ='checkRequest(e)'>
   //rest of code
</body>

function checkRequest(event){
   let __type= event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type;
    if(__type === 1){
      // alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
   }
else if(__type ==2){
    //Browser back button is clicked
   }
}
```

You can also visit this [link](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2013/12/browser-back-button-click-event.html)

Comment: please create a demo

Comment: created but nothing happen

Comment: Please share the demo link

Comment: I am working o local can you create this discussion chat.

Answer (score 0):

Help taken from answer of @brk.
Reference Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Words related to stopping page reload:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Syntax

```
<?php
    echo '<br>GET PARAMETERS=<pre>'. print_r($_GET, true) .'</pre><br>';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body onbeforeunload ='checkRequest(event)'>
        ABC
        <form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="">
            <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="<?php echo ( isset($_GET['text1']) ? $_GET['text1'] : '' ) ?>">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkRequest(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.returnValue = '';
                var __type= event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type;
                if(__type === 1 || __type === 0){
                    // alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
                    document.getElementById('frm1').submit();
                }
                else if(__type ==2){
                    alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is work when user use ctrl+r if the user reloads the page click on "reload this page"

Comment: have edited the answer, if you do console.log for variable __type, you will get to know. What are all values are getting retrieved in that variable. Whenever, user do not makes any changes and just reloads the page either using ctrl + r or just f5. __type returns 0, and whenever user enters anything in textbox, then __type returns 1, that's why edited the if condition to handle both instances.